# LaTex (TexWorks) компиляция: Ошибка "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом"

Tags: windows-10, latex

В TexWorks под Windows 10 пытаюсь скомпилировать Latex-file в pdf. Компиляция проваливается, в log-файле несколько раз встречается ошибка:

```
FATAL texify - Windows API error 32: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.
```

Задача в том, чтобы сверстать pdf, содержащим одновременно русский и английский текст. Если делать только на английском, то всё ок. Как только второй файл пытаюсь скомпилировать двуязычным - получаю такую странную проблему.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где может быть ошибка (или ошибки).

Начало файла:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
    \textheight=700px                    % Saving trees ;-)
\usepackage{url}

\frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers

%%% Custom sectioning (sectsty package)
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{%                      % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}}


\newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name
        \noindent \Huge \usefont{OT1}{cmr}{b}{n} #1 \hfill 
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\MyJobTitle}[1]{ % Name
        \noindent \usefont{OT1}{cmr}{b}{n} #1 \hfill 
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\MyContact}[1]{ % Slogan (optional)
        \large \usefont{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n} #1
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\section*{{\color{gray}\uppercase{#1}}}}

\newcommand{\SkillsEntry}[2]{\textbf{#1}: #2}  
        
\newcommand{\ExperienceEntry}[4]{
        \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill  
        \hfill #2 \par  % Duration
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par        % School
        \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
        \normalsize \par}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\MyName{Something}
\MyJobTitle{engineer}
\columnbreak
\MyContact{\faEnvelope : email@gmail.com}
\MyContact{\faLinkedin : link}
\end{multicols}

\NewPart{Work experience}{}

\ExperienceEntry
{engineer}
{dates}
{name) $\vert$ location}
{Описание проекта}
{   
\begin{itemize}
    \item{Русский текст с english words))}
\end{itemize}
}
```

Comment: Такая ерунда происходит, когда программа пытается писать в файл открытый другим процессом. Ну, например Вы открыли сгенерированный pdf и не закрывая его снова пытаетесь его сгенерировать внеся правки в исходник, а  старый в это время все еще открыт. Проверьте это для начала. Если внутренняя ошибка (ну мало ли...) попробуйте другой, например TeXstudio